# Is the sentence "Ice Cream Sandwich guinea pig" wrong due to the lack of apostrophe?

Tags: grammar

I just saw this headline on the internet: "Galaxy Nexus: Android Ice Cream Sandwich guinea pig".

My knowledge in English  tells me the construction is wrong because of a missing apostrophe after "sandwich", but in the website I saw it nobody seemed to point this out.

I saw a print screen of it on Reddit, by the way, but since it was a headline of an article, I assume any mistakes would have been pointed out.

Is this sentence construction wrong?

Comment: Unless there's some sort of possession going on (which could be metaphorical), you don't want an apostrophe in there. But they're talkign about a guinea pig ***for*** Android Ice Cream Sandwich, not a guinea pig ***owned by*** Android Ice Cream Sandwich or a guinea pig ***of*** Android Ice Cream Sandwich. So using an apostrophe would be wrong.

Comment: Your cited headline is ***not*** a "sentence". As [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Ice_Cream_Sandwich), *Android 4.0 "Ice Cream Sandwich" is a version of the Android mobile operating system developed by Google.* What that means is "Ice Cream Sandwich" is a *name* (effectively therefore, a *Noun Phrase = NP*). In this context, it's being used *adjectivally* to modify another NP ("guinea pig"), so the entire text **Android Ice Cream Sandwich guinea pig** is an NP. Preceding it by a completely different NP ("Galaxy Nexus") doesn't result in a sentence. ***There's no verb.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Are we referring to 'Android Ice Cream Sandwich' as a brand name or as a real-world project?

Let me replace 'Android Ice Cream Sandwich' with 'iPhone', and 'guinea pig' with 'experiment' to make it easier to read:

> Apple announced the launch of their new iPhone experiment

Apple has a new experiment. It's not just any old experiment, it's an *iPhone* experiment. I'm using 'iPhone' as a brand name here.

> Apple announced the launch of their new iPhone's experiment

Apple doesn't have a new experiment, Apple's new iPhone has an experiment. I'm using 'iPhone' in this sentence as a real world product, not as an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

It's only "wrong" to not use possessive case if proper nouns or a noun referring to a person are involved.

> The coat is John's.
>
> This is the king's crown.

Otherwise, it does not "have" to be used.  It can be clearer, or impart a "personable" quality, if you do use it, though.

> This is the operating system's method of telling you there is a problem.
>
> This is the operating system method of telling you there is a problem.
>
> The calculator's display was broken.
>
> The calculator display was broken.